# VBA Incrementing Date Error

Tags: vba, date, excel

I've never done VBA before but a friend has asked for help so I've been working on his project. I'm trying to increment a given date by one day but I'm getting an "Object Required" error in the DateAdd function. As far as I can tell I'm putting in an object (firstDate)...

The date entered,for my testing purposes at least, has been 12/03/2012 in that format.
The Format and CDate functions seem to work fine and parse the date.

Here's the code, I get the error at the line with DateAdd in it.

```
Sub GetDate()

Dim strDate As String

strDate = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the first day of the week in dd/mm/yyyy format.", _
      title:="First day of the week", Default:="")

    If strDate = "" Or strDate = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim firstDate As Date
        firstDate = CDate(Format(strDate, "Short Date"))

        'Add to O and 6 after
        For inc = 0 To 6 Step 1
            Range(Chr(79 + inc) & 1) = firstDate
            firstDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, firstDate)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `DateAdd("d", 1, firstDate)`  You seem to be mixing up VBA and .NET in your question (and tags).  Best to pick one...

Comment: Ah I'm not familiar with the .Net framework, I thought VB was part it of it. I'll try your suggestion now thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works :) if you put that as an answer I'll mark it correct. If you could also explain why that works as well and the DateInterval.Day didn't that'd be great. I thought DateInterval.Day was the enumerated value so that would just return whatever vba uses to represent "Day"...

Comment: Also how do you mean I'm mixing up VBA and .NET in my question? Thanks.

Comment: Tim and JFC have already given you solutions. Here is one suggestion from me. Since you are using a `InputBox` for accepting Date, you might want to change `If strDate = "" Or strDate = vbNullString Then
` to `If strDate = "" Or strDate = vbNullString Or IsDate(strDate) = False Then`

Comment: Peanut - what @Tim means is that `DateInterval.Day` **is** .NET syntax.  In VBA, the first parameter of DateAdd is a string, not an enumerated value. The string "d" is for day. See the [Office help page for DateAdd](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx). VBA and VB.NET are two different things. VBA follows the VB6 syntax.

Comment: Thanks for that Sidd I'll put it in and thanks transistor, I wasn't aware VBA wasn't part of the .NET framework and didn't know VBA and VB.NET were different things. I mostly program in Java with limited experience in C# so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very well...

`DateAdd("d", 1, firstDate)`

But: I'm not that fussed if anyone reposts a comment of mine as an answer. I **do** read the comments as well as the answers.  Maybe because I have this habit of suggesting answers in comments...

Comment: My intention was to get the correct answer in the correct place. I'm sorry if it seemed otherwise.

Comment: There you go Tim. I also read the comments but I think it's in the spirit of the site to also have an actual answer marked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

You're just trying to increment by one day, right?

```
firstDate = firstDate + 1
```

The unit of the `Date` type is one day. So adding 1 adds one day.

Comment: By the way, you should declare `Dim firstDate As Date` to avoid any ambiguity as to its type. In fact, you should always declare all your variables using `Dim`, and force yourself to do this using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Comment: Ah I thought I'd tried that and got a type mismatch but just tried it again and it works. Also I do declare firstDate like that. I'll mark this as correct since Tim hasn't posted his answer.